# Windows 10 emulators not showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Earlier today I had everything set up for developing for Windows 10 mobile in VS 2015, but had some issues with the connection to my emulator, when I started it up. So I decided to delete the emulators from the Hyper-v manager. I thought that I could just reinstall them, but I haven't found a way to make them show in the Hyper-V manager again. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the sdk, vs15 and disabling/enabling hyper-v, but they don't even show up as a device in vs15. Instead I'm only left with a choice to download them but they never appear after I download them. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to re-install the Hyper-v. I also had the connection issue to windows 10 mobile emulator. And I resolved it by re-install the hyper-v.

Comment: Have you tried doing a VS repair? That might restore them.

Comment: Yeah, I tried disabling and enabling hyper-v. Don't know if that's the same thing as reinstalling it? I will try a VS repair and see what happens. Thanks for the advice guys!

Comment: The VS repair did the trick! Thank you!